# HTML Bootstrap Column/Grid Image Glitch

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm trying to get a Bootstrap grid to get 2 images side by side for this project I need for FreeCodeCamp.com  ,  the images are the same size, but I can't get the code to work, as they will appear one smaller and one larger, or just not fill the line properly. What I'm getting is http://codepen.io/KlausMana/pen/vKZwpW , and the images just seem out of place. EDIT: Some code is not showing up on StackOverflow, so I'll just put the rest in quotations in here: "
     
          
    
    " I can't yet see it for some reason... I don't know why this is happening, if you can edit this post and make it visible, I hope it is just me...

Code:

```
<style>

.main-text{
color:#655370;
font-family:"Gothic";
font-size:60px;
background-color:#38486B;
}
body{
background-color:#5988FF;
}
.secondary-text{
color:#3F393E;
  font-family:"Gothic";
font-size:30px;
background-color:#7BA0FC
}
</style>
<center><h1 class="main-text">Steve Jobs, in Loving Memory</h1></center>
<i><center><h2 class="secondary-text">In tribute to a great man,  a man we                 all loved...</h2></center></i>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
 <img src="http://unisci24.com/data_images/wlls/47/334765-steve-jobs.jpg"       alt="Steve Jobs 1" class="img-responsive">
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the images and host them yourself. You are adding responsive class to images that have already been rendered.